# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module error in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, typescript-eslint

After adding the mui-tel-input package to my React project, I encounter this error when trying to build. I couldn't find how to solve it.

```
Linting and checking validity of types
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Collecting page data  ...C:\Projects\xxx\yyy\node_modules\mui-tel-input\dist\mui-tel-input.es.js:1
import { jsx as N, jsxs as H, Fragment as Fe } from "react/jsx-runtime";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at mod.require (C:\Projects\xxx\yyy\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at 476 (C:\Projects\xxx\yyy\.next\server\pages\add-customer.js:1:3517)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /add-customer
    at C:\Projects\xxx\yyy\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1220:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
   Collecting page data  .
```

I added

`"type": "module"`

and

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(mui-tel-input)).*\\.js$"
    ]
  }
```

to the package.json in the root directory, but my problem was not

Comment: What node version are you using? It seems like your environment does not support ES6 modules. Node.js added support for ES6 in the version 13.2.0. Double-check your Node.js version. 

Also, you could use a modified form of import statement: ```const { jsx: N, jsxs: H, Fragment: Fe } = require("react/jsx-runtime"); ``` in